# Rails 3.1 API Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a Rails 3.1 app that I want to create an API for. I want my urls to look something like:

```
www.example.com/controller/action // Normal Web requests
api.example.com/controller/action.json // API requests
```

The first one would be for normal requests and the other obviously for my API stuff. I would like both of these to map to the same controller/action.

How do I set up my application so that it only responds to HTML when on www and json, xml, etc when I am on the api subdomain?

Comment: If you are intending to build an API to be used externally, I would advise to use separate controllers. The error-handling is totally different for an API and the UI. Also handling exceptions is for us totally different. If an API method triggers an exception, we format it to xml and return it with the correct HTTP-state.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The easiest way (imo) would be, to use Rails 3 routing constraints. In config/routes.rb, use:

```
constraints :subdomain => 'www', :format => :html do
  # Routing for normal web requests
  match 'mycontroller/:action' => 'mycontroller#index'
  # ...
end

constraints :subdomain => 'api', :format => :json do
  # Routing for API requests
  match 'mycontroller/:action.:format' => 'mycontroller#index'
  # ...
end
```

You might also want to have a look into [respond_with](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with) (and respond_to at class level), which makes it much easier to write controllers that respond to multiple formats than with traditional respond_to.

Answer (score 3):

Check [#221 Subdomains in Rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3) Rails Cast. For www you can put additional contstraint ":format => :html".
Another solution would be using controller filter which checks request.subdomain and params[:format]. Then you don't need to duplicate routes.

Answer (score 0):

Would [subdomain-fu](https://github.com/mbleigh/subdomain-fu) be of help?